# Custom font to be rendered in Django using Amazon s3

Tags: css, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to read the documentation and still could not figure out how to render custom fonts in Django through s3 buckets.

`styles.css`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('../static/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400; 
}
```

`settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

#s3 buckets config


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
# AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ap-south-1'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

`Cors Configuration`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:8000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The code works fine in local environment.
Do I need AWS lambda for this or the absolute path defined in styles.css  `src: url('../static/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf');` is incorrect?

Any help will be much appreciated..Thanks!

Comment: what is your  global  address   on which you can  open .otf file?
http://example.com/static/fonts/yourfont.otf. Is it reachable  from  browser?

Comment: Not able to reach since every url has signature attach to it

Comment: I can see what you're trying to do, and I am having the same challenge. I've even tried entering the full S3 url into the css url parameter with no luck. I'm unable to solve this currently.

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNova';
  src: url('/static/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400; 
}
```

Replace "../" with "/". So your url will be readed according to the root of your host.

Comment: can  you reach 'yourhost.com/static/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf  file or any other file?

Comment: Yes, using localhost everything is fine

Comment: So the problem is in reaching it on remote host? Which http server is being used?

Comment: I think  that  you can not reach any of your static files, right?

Comment: I just cant access fonts

Comment: try /media/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf and ensure that you have that file in media folder, but anyway this is very wierd